# Knockout Validation for all text inputs

Tags: javascript, validation, knockout.js, knockout-validation

I have requirement to set regexp validation on all input fields.
I have done it by overriding value binding of knockout.
Below is the code approach.

```
var defaultInit = ko.bindingHandlers.value.init;
var defaultUpdate = ko.bindingHandlers.value.update;
var setValidationExtender = function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, options) {
    if (element.tagName.toLowerCase() === "input" &&
        element.type === "text" && !element.disabled &&
        !element.hidden && valueAccessor) {
        if (allBindings() && ko.isObservable(allBindings().value)) {
            allBindings().value.extend(options);
        }

    }
};
ko.bindingHandlers.value = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
        defaultInit(element, valueAccessor, allBindings);
        setValidationExtender(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, {
            allowedChars: {
                params: element
            }
        });
    },
    update: defaultUpdate
};
```

I want to be sure that this approach is acceptable by knockout principles.
For Validation used [knockout validation lib](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation). Knockout.js version 3.2.0.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Without looking at the code itself, I'd advice you to not overwrite the default bindings. Why not create a `validatedValue` binding? You can still call the default `value` binding's `update` and `init` methods.

Comment: thanks for answer , actually that was the second approach which I decided to do , but it's huge change to current implementation in system, which is not preferable for now.